# Pass member function pointer to parent class yields compiler error

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'd like to have child classes register callbacks to their parent class so that users of the parent class can call methods of the child with a known function signature.

```
typedef int(*Func)(int);

class A
{
  public:
    void registerFunc(Func f)
    {}
};

class B : public A
{

  public:
    B()
    {
      A::registerFunc(&B::myF);
    }
    int myF(int x) {
       // do stuff with member variables
       return 3; 
    }
};
```

But I get this compiler error

```
main.cpp:18:23: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Func' (aka 'int (*)(int)') with an rvalue of type 'int (B::*)(int)'
      A::registerFunc(&B::myF);
                      ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:28: note: passing argument to parameter 'f' here
    void registerFunc(Func f)
```

Here's a Repl illustrating the error in a concise example.

https://replit.com/@Carpetfizz/RudeSmoothComments#main.cpp

The accepted answer in a related thread suggested to override a virtual function declared in `A` but my use case actually requires dynamic callback registrations.

Comment: A `int (B::*)(int)` is not a `int (*)(int)`.  That is the long and short of it. `B::myF` requires an implicit `B` (or derivative) to work upon. What was your plan to provide that if all you're passing to `registerFunc` is a simple non-static member function? Non-static member functions need an instance. That's the question that needs to be answered *first* . There are ways to do that dynamically, but it must be done nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks - I thought member function *pointers* have access to the member variables of the instance of the class they belong to. If I were to make this a static function that took in `const B&` as a parameter, and something else passed an `&A` into it, would I have to static cast it to `B` before using it?

Comment: When being called from/with an instance, non-static member fn's do have access. But they need an instance *first*. static member functions do NOT need an instance (and thus cannot access non-static member variables, because there's no "there" there). What is the real goal here? That somewhere within `A` code an invoke of the 'thing' passed to `registerFunc` will invoke upon that instance-of-`A` derivative? I think the research you did is close to what you need, if not exact, and its just a misunderstanding that lead you down the `Func` path.

Comment: Yeah, so say some other class `C` has a vector of `A`s and it knows that each `A` has a `Func` of a known signature, but each `Func` could be a pointer to some derived class of `A`, such as `B`. `C` doesn't (and shouldn't) care about what happens inside each `Func` or what member variables it uses. It just cares about what it passes in and what it gets out. I think `std::function` and `std::bind` will help me out here?

Comment: A non-static member function's `this` is an implicit parameter, so the signature can't match a static member function or a regular old function.  What you're trying to do is possible, but you'll need to use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to store the registered functions, and [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to construct something to pass to the registration function that's bound to an object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the goal (and believe me, that's a sketchy 'if'), you want to specify some member of some `A` derivation to invoke from some `A` member as a dispatched 'callback' mechanic. If that is the case, then to answer your question in comment, yes, a function and bind can do this. It can even be semi-protected with a little help from sfinae:

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;

    std::function<void(int)> callback = [](int){};

    template<class Derived>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, Derived>::value>
    registerCallback(void (Derived::*pfn)(int))
    {
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        callback = std::bind(pfn, dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this), _1);
    }

    void fire(int arg)
    {
        callback(arg);
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void memberfn(int arg)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << arg << '\n';
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    void memberfn(int arg)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << arg << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_unique<B>();
    ptr->registerCallback(&B::memberfn);
    // ptr->registerCallback(&Foo::memberfn); // WILL NOT WORK
    ptr->fire(42);
}
```

**Output**

```
void B::memberfn(int):42
```

**The Parts**

The first part is straight forward. We declare a member variable `callback` to be a `std::function<void(int)>` instance. This is where we'll eventually bind our callable object point. The default value is a lambda that does nothing.

---

The second part is... a little more complicated:

```
template<class Derived>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, Derived>::value>
registerCallback(void (Derived::*pfn)(int))
```

This declares `registerCallback` as an available member function that accepts a non-static member function pointer taking one `int` as an argument, but *only* if the class hosting that member function, or a derivative therein, is a derivation of `A` (or `A` itself). Some non-`A` derivative `Foo` with a member `void foo(int)` will *not* compile.

---

Next, the setup to the callback itself.

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
callback = std::bind(pfn, dymamic_cast<Derived*>(this), _1);
```

This just binds the pointer-to-member to `this` dynamic-cast to the derivation type (which had better work or we're in trouble, see final warning at the end of this diatribe), and sets the call-time placeholder. The `_1` you see comes from the `std::placeholders` namespace, and is used to delay providing an argument to the callback until such time as we actually invoke it (where it will be required,and you'll see that later). See [`std::placehholders`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) for more information.

---

Finally, the `fire` member, which does this:

```
void fire(int arg)
{
    callback(arg);
}
```

This invokes the registered function object with the provided argument. Both the member function *and* `this` are already wired into the object. The argument `arg` is used to fill in the placeholder we mentioned earlier.

---

The test driver for this is straightforward:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_unique<B>();
    ptr->registerCallback(&B::memberfn);
    // ptr->registerCallback(&Foo::memberfn); // WILL NOT WORK
    ptr->fire(42);
}
```

This creates a new `B`, hosting it in a dynamic `A` pointer (so you know there is no funny business going on). Even with that, because `B` derived from `A` the `registerCallback` sfinae filtering passes inspection and the callback is registered successfully. We then invoke the `fire` method, passing our `int` argument `42`, which will be sent to the callback, etc.

---

**Warning: With great power comes great responsibility**

Even those there is protection from passing non-`A` derived member functions, there is absolutely none from the casting itself. It would be trivial to craft a basic `A`, pass a `B` member (which will work since `A` is its base), but there is no `B` actually present.

You can catch this at runtime via that `dynamic_cast`, which we're currently *not* error checking. For example:

```
registerCallback(void (Derived::*pfn)(int))
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    Derived *p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this);
    if (p)
        callback = std::bind(pfn, p, _1);
}
```

You can choose the road more risky. Personally, i'd detect the null case and throw an exception just to be safe(er)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
typedef std::function<int (int)> Func;

class A
{
  public:
    void registerFunc(Func f)
    {}
};

class B : public A
{

  public:
    B()
    {
      A::registerFunc(std::bind(&B::myF, *this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    int myF(int x) {
       // do stuff with member variables
       return 3;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate on placeholders?